# Enviar variáveis para PHP via Ajax - variáveis indefinidas

Tags: php, ajax, variáveis

Estou tentando enviar dados de um arquivo PHP para outro através de Ajax, mas as variáveis estão indo indefinidas (no alert, exibe: "Notice: Undefined variable:").

Uma descrição breve da estrutura usada (talvez isso influencie no erro): tenho um arquivo principal **index.php** que utiliza uma classe para paginação de resultados **Pagina_result.php**. Nessa classe, se é o último registro, o botão (em HTML) não exibe o valor "Avançar", mas sim "Finalizar", e deve gravar variáveis que identificam a série acessada no BD.

Na classe Pagina_result.php:

```
if ( $current_page != $total_of_pages ) { 
            /*Monta o "Avançar"*/
        } else {
            print " <button type=\"button\" value=\"Finalizar\" class=\"Accesso\" id=\"finalizar\"> ";

        }
```

O definição das variáveis em PHP:

```
<?php
    $servico    = ( isset( $_GET['servico'] ) ? $_GET['servico'] : 0 );
    $sessao     = ( isset( $_GET['id'] )   ? $_GET['id']   : 0 );
    $user       = ( isset( $_SESSION['usrid'] )   ? $_SESSION['usrid']   : 0 );
?>
```

O código Ajax para enviar as variáveis referentes ao item para gravação:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#finalizar").click( function() {
           $.ajax({
              type:'post',
              url:'sessUser.php',
              data:{ 'servico': <?php echo $servico; ?>, 'sessao': <?php echo $sessao; ?>, 'user': <?php echo $user; ?>, }
            }).done( function( data ) {
                alert(data);
            });
        });
    });

    </script>
```

E, por último, o arquivo **sessUser.php**, que deveria receber os dados:

```
<?php

$servico = $_POST['servico'];
$sessao = $_POST['sessao'];
$user = $_POST['user'];

function inclusao() {
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("db", $link);
    $inserir = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabela (id_servico, id_sessao, id_user)values('".$servico."','".$sessao."','".$user."')", $link);
}

inclusao();
?>
```

Já tentei de tudo, mas não consigo achar o erro... Apesar das variáveis estarem indefinidas, a gravação é feita no BD, mas com os valores = 0.

Comment: São todas strings essas variaveis do post?

Comment: Como é que esse jQuery aparece no lado do cliente? (já renderizado)

Comment: @Diego Felipe as duas primeiras variáveis são strings. A variável "user" provém de uma session com o ID do usuário (int incremental no BD).

Comment: @Sergio vc quer saber da renderização no código fonte da página?

Comment: Sim, quero ver como aparece esse data dentro do objeto ajax para tentar perceber qual pode ser o erro...

Comment: Ele fica assim: `<script language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#finalizar").click( function() {
      $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url:'sessUser.php',
      data:{ 'servico': 20, 'sessao': 15, 'user': 8, }
    }).done( function( data ) {
              alert(data);
          });
   });
  });
  
  </script>`  Aparentemente preenche o data com os dados que eu queria, mas não envia adiante...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o problema esta no arquivo **sessUser.php**.

As variáveis estão sendo setadas fora da função e utilizadas dentro da função, o que pode causar os valores zerados.

Tente esse código abaixo e verifique se resolve o problema:

```
<?php

$servico = $_POST['servico'];
$sessao = $_POST['sessao'];
$user = $_POST['user'];

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("db", $link);
$inserir = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabela (id_servico, id_sessao, id_user)values('".$servico."','".$sessao."','".$user."')", $link);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A função não encontra as variaveis, considere usar global na função

```
<?php

$servico = $_POST['servico'];
$sessao = $_POST['sessao'];
$user = $_POST['user'];

function inclusao() {
    global $servico, $sessao, $user;
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("db", $link);
    $inserir = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabela (id_servico, id_sessao, id_user)values('".$servico."','".$sessao."','".$user."')", $link);
}

inclusao();
?>
```

ou passar como parâmetro para a função

```
<?php

    $servico = $_POST['servico'];
    $sessao = $_POST['sessao'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];

    function inclusao($servico, $sessao, $user) {
        $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        mysql_select_db("db", $link);
        $inserir = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabela (id_servico, id_sessao, id_user)values('".$servico."','".$sessao."','".$user."')", $link);
    }

    inclusao($servico, $sessao, $user);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

No arquivo *sessUser.php*, está resgatando o `$_POST` e atribuindo a variáveis fora do escopo da função `inclusao()`.

Mova as variáveis para dentro da função:

```
<?php


function inclusao() {

    $servico = $_POST['servico'];
    $sessao = $_POST['sessao'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];

    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("db", $link);
    $inserir = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tabela (id_servico, id_sessao, id_user)values('".$servico."','".$sessao."','".$user."')", $link);
}

inclusao();
?>
```

Outro meio é passar por parâmetros

```
inclusao($servico, $sessao, $user)
```

ou invocar o global

```
function inclusao() {
    global $servico, $sessao, $user
```